# use jq and loop through the json and get multiple values

Tags: json, jq

I have the command to get individual responses using jq from a json file. but multiple values are not getting displayed when I use [].
This is my json

```
{
  "status" : "UP",
  "details" : {
    "Service1" : {
      "status" : "UP",
      "details" : {
        "Credit" : {
          "status" : "UP",
          "details" : {
            "Tablename" : "credittable"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Service2" : {
      "status" : "UP",
      "details" : {
        "Debit" : {
          "status" : "UP",
          "details" : {
            "Tablename" : "debittable"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Service3" : {
      "status" : "UP",
      "details" : {
        "Loan" : {
          "status" : "UP",
          "details" : {
            "Tablename" : "loantable"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below are my commands:

```
cat api.json | jq '.details.Service1.status'
cat api.json | jq '.details.Service1.details.Credit.status'
cat api.json | jq '.details.Service1.details.Credit.details.TableName
```

currently assigning these values to individual variables and then doing an echo wanted to see if we can have a loop and display all with one command.

I am trying to print as below

```
Service1  up  
credittable  up  
Service2 UP  
debittable up  
Service3 up  
loantable up
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the -r option, the following filter:

```
.details
| to_entries[]
| "\(.key) \(.value.status)",
  (.value.details[]
   | "\(.details.Tablename) \(.status)" )
```

produces the desired output.

Comment: Keep getting this error... jq -r .details | to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value.status)",(.value.details[] | "\(.details.Tablename) \(.status)" )  health.json
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `.value.details[]'

Comment: Either quote the jq appropriately for your shell, or even better perhaps, copy the jq program into a file and use the -f command-line option.

Comment: jq -f this.jq sample.json
"Service1 UP"
"null UP"
"Service2 UP"
"null UP"
"Service3 UP"
"null UP"

Comment: Tablename is not coming up.. tried different ways .. Its coming as empty